# TFS: Is is possible to transfer all checked out files from one user to another?

Tags: tfs

I am developer and work with TFS for a while but never have the responsibility of TFS admin. We have a user that was let go and now his userId has been revoked so we cannot use his id anymore.

He has so many files checked out in TFS and a lot of stuff done, we don't want to lose these checked out files if possible. Is there a way to transfer all his checked out files to me or someone else? Or what is the best way to recover these files?

NOTE: we still have his laptop with all the files, we just cant login to it with his username.

Thank you for your help in advanced

Answer (score 3):

1. **Download [TFS Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) (get the right version for your TFS)**

They have a Visual Studio Add-in if that is what you are using as your IDE

2. **Backup his files that you want to keep**
3. **Use the Workspace Sidekick of TFS Sidekicks to delete his workspace(s)** 
   (this won't delete his files).

This will release any exclusive locks that he has effectively undoing all his checkouts.

You can also use the Status Sidekick to see what files he has checked out.

4. **Get latest source and copy his files over yours**

If you are using TFS2012 or later, you can use a 'local' workspace and simply copy his files over. Team Explorer will create your pending changes for you. If you are using a 'server' workspace or a version of TFS prior to 2012, you will need to full check-out everything and THEN copy his files over.

It's not a great solution but it should work for you

Comment: Thanks Suited Aces, I'll try this.

Comment: You don't have to login, please see my update answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32586769/2074346

Answer (score 1):

The changes to the developer's files that are checked out will be stored locally on the developers machine (specifically in their workspace directories) - transferring "check out status" would seemingly not accomplish what you hope.

You would need to obtain access to the developer's workspace (perhaps via an admin account on the dev's machine), copy out all the contents to a new workspace you own to consolidate differences between "source" and "new workspace".

Once you've copied the developer's workspace to a new workspace you own, you can simply compare "source" to "workspace" to find all the changed files and which are needed vs. not needed.  Note, this should be done sooner rather than later as the longer you wait the more differences there will be between the two, making it harder to identify what is actually needed.